# How to create a copy of a dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe from which I need to create a new dataframe with a small change in the schema by doing the following operation.

```
>>> X = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], ['a', 'b'])
>>> schema_new = X.schema.add('id_col', LongType(), False)
>>> _X = X.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda l: list(l[0]) + [l[1]]).toDF(schema_new)
```

The problem is that in the above operation, the schema of `X` gets changed inplace. So when I print `X.columns` I get

```
>>> X.columns
['a', 'b', 'id_col']
```

but the values in `X` are still the same

```
>>> X.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

To avoid changing the schema of `X`, I tried creating a copy of `X` using three ways 
- using `copy` and `deepcopy` methods from the `copy` module
- simply using `_X = X`

The `copy` methods failed and returned a

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The assignment method also doesn't work

```
>>> _X = X
>>> id(_X) == id(X)
True
```

Since their `id` are the same, creating a duplicate dataframe doesn't really help here and the operations done on `_X` reflect in `X`.

So my question really is two fold

- how to change the schema outplace (that is without making any changes to `X`)?
- and more importantly, how to create a duplicate of a pyspark dataframe?

**Note:**

This question is a followup to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275705/ambiguous-behavior-while-adding-new-column-to-structtype)

Comment: The simplest solution that comes to my mind is using a work around with `df_copy = original_df.select("*")`, And maybe add some .cache() . Make it sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As explained in the answer to the other question, you could make a deepcopy of your initial schema. We can then modify that copy and use it to initialize the new `DataFrame` `_X`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType
import copy

X = spark.createDataFrame([[1,2], [3,4]], ['a', 'b'])
_schema = copy.deepcopy(X.schema)
_schema.add('id_col', LongType(), False) # modified inplace
_X = X.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda l: list(l[0]) + [l[1]]).toDF(_schema)
```

Now let's check:

```
print('Schema of X: ' + str(X.schema))
print('Schema of _X: ' + str(_X.schema))
```

Output:

```
Schema of X: StructType(List(StructField(a,LongType,true),StructField(b,LongType,true)))
Schema of _X: StructType(List(StructField(a,LongType,true),
                  StructField(b,LongType,true),StructField(id_col,LongType,false)))
```

Note that to copy a `DataFrame` you can just use `_X = X`. Whenever you add a new column with e.g. `withColumn`, the object is not altered in place, but a new copy is returned. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 33):

`.alias()` is commonly used in renaming the columns, but it is also [a DataFrame method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.alias) and will give you what you want:

```py
df2 = df.alias('df2')
id(df2) == id(df)  # False
```

Comment: @GuillaumeLabs can you please tell your spark version and what error you got.

Comment: I'm using azure databricks 6.4 . The Ids of dataframe are different but because initial dataframe was a select of a delta table, the copy of this dataframe with your trick is still a select of this delta table ;-) .

Comment: Try reading from a table, making a copy, then writing that copy back to the source location. "Cannot overwrite table."  So this solution might not be perfect.

Answer (score 3):

```
df2 = df.select("*")
id(df2) = id(df)  # False
```

This is identical to the answer given by @SantiagoRodriguez, and likewise represents a similar approach to what @tozCSS shared. I believe @tozCSS's suggestion of using `.alias()` in place of `.select()` may indeed be the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to create a copy of a pyspark dataframe, you could potentially use Pandas (if your use case allows it).

```
schema = X.schema
X_pd = X.toPandas()
_X = spark.createDataFrame(X_pd,schema=schema)
del X_pd
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala:

1. With "X.schema.copy" new schema instance created without old schema modification;
2. In each Dataframe operation, which return Dataframe ("select","where", etc), new Dataframe is created, without modification of original. Original can be used again and again. Guess, duplication is not required for yours case. Performance is separate issue, "persist" can be used.

Answer (score 1):

To create a **Deep copy** of a PySpark DataFrame, you can use the rdd method to extract the data as an RDD, and then create a new DataFrame from the RDD.

```
df_deep_copied = spark.createDataFrame(df_original.rdd.map(lambda x: x), schema=df_original.schema)
```

**Note:** This method can be memory-intensive, so use it judiciously.